# Cannot use query hint with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I have a collection that contains documents in the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : "id1",
    "closedAt" : ISODate("2019-04-01T15:19:34.189Z"),
    "attempts" : [{
            "successful" : false
        }],
    "version" : 1,
}
```

where `closedAt` is optional and may be non-existent. 
I also have an index defined like this:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "closedAt" : 1,
        "attempts.successful" : 1
    },
    "name" : "closed_at_and_attempts_successful_idx",
    "ns" : "x",
    "sparse" : true
}
```

I can ask mongo to return documents that doesn't have a `closedAt` field and only has attempts where `successful` is `false` with a hint to use the `closed_at_and_attempts_successful_idx` index:

```
db.x.find({"$and": [{ "closedAt" : {"$exists":false}}, {"attempts.successful" : {"$all" : [false]}}]}).hint("closed_at_and_attempts_successful_idx")
```

This returns me the correct results in the MobgoDB console. However I'm using Spring Boot 2.1 and Spring Data MongoDB (reactive) and I fail to convert this to be usable from Spring. I've tried numerous approaches, for example:

```
val document = Document.parse("{'\$and' : [{'attempts.successful' : {'\$eq' : false}},{'\$nor' : [{'closedAt' : {'\$exists' : true}}]}]}")
val query = BasicQuery(document).withHint("{ 'closed_at_and_attempts_successful_idx' : 1 }")
return mongoReactiveOperations.find(query, X::class.java). ..
```

and

```
val q: Bson = and(Arrays.asList(exists("closedAt", false), all("chargingAttempts.successful", Arrays.asList(false))))
return mongo.getCollection("x").find(q).hint("closed_at_and_attempts_successful_idx").toFlux().map { source ->
    mongo.converter.read(X::class.java, source)
}. ..
```

but all my attempts fail with:

```java
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=order.order batchSize=256Tree: $and
    attempts.successful $eq false
    $not
        closedAt exists
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: bad hint' on server localhost:27017
```

It seem to work if I remove the query hint.

Q: How can I exec my query with the specified hint in Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I've opened [DATAMONGO-2249](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2249) to investigate on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this:

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.withHint("lastUpdateDate_-1");
mongoTemplate.find(query, SomeClass.class);
```

the argument of method `withHint` is the index name;

the index name should be the index name in your database, not the column name, not json string as you write;